# Exploding an array in PHP with three delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, explode

I have an array which I want to explode. The array has three delimiters which I want to place in three different variables.

Here is the array:-

```
the_first|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
the_second|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
the_third|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
```

Here is what I did:-

```
$extra_details =  "has the above array"


                  $array = array();
                  foreach ($extra_details as $r) {
                    $array[] = explode("|", $r);
                  }
```

I hope I can get each in multi-dimensional array which I can then use.

Comment: So what are the delimiters? I can see `|` and I'm guessing that the second is the new line, so what's the third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got there looks like CSV, just not comma separated, but using a pipe. [The function `str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) should be working in that case:

```
$inputString = <<<EOS
    the_first|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
    the_second|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
    the_third|Little Detail|Some Large Details with a para of text
EOS;

$outputArray = str_getcsv( $inputString, '|');
```

Comment: @Steve Yeah, but without your example the question really was it bit meager…